# on ubuntu 18.04 set TUNSETQUEUE always get faild

Tags: linux, tap, tunnel, tun

i want to open tun with multiqueue,but when i set IFF_ATTACH_QUEUE failed.

Linux version 4.15.0-62-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-024) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1))

```
int tun_alloc_mq(char *dev, int queues, int *fds)
  {
      struct ifreq ifr;
      int fd, err, i;

      if (!dev)
          return -1;

      memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
      /* Flags: IFF_TUN   - TUN device (no Ethernet headers)
       *        IFF_TAP   - TAP device
       *
       *        IFF_NO_PI - Do not provide packet information
       *        IFF_MULTI_QUEUE - Create a queue of multiqueue device
       */
      ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI | IFF_MULTI_QUEUE;
      strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev);

      for (i = 0; i < queues; i++) {
          if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) < 0)
             goto err;
          err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr);
          if (err) {
             close(fd);
             goto err;
          }
          fds[i] = fd;
      }

      return 0;
  err:
      for (--i; i >= 0; i--)
          close(fds[i]);
      return err;
} 

int tun_set_queue(int fd, int enable)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    //strcpy(ifr.ifr_name,"tun1");
    if (enable)
        ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_ATTACH_QUEUE;
    else
        ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_DETACH_QUEUE;

    if(ioctl(fd, TUNSETQUEUE, (void *)&ifr) < 0)
    {
        printf("ioctl:%s\n",strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

function tun_set_queue will get "ioctl:Invalid argument"

Comment: Have u resolved the problem?